# Why are base-change matrices always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

I noticed something strange in my linear algebra lecture notes: the notes state that the base-change matrix that has m rows and n columns will always be invertible.. but how can that be? If m doesn't equal n how can the matrix be invertible?

Comment: Well they are bases for the same vector space so it must be that $m = n$.  This may not be obvious but if you read up on dimension, you should find the proof.

Comment: In this context the singular of _bases_ is _basis_, not _base_.

Comment: Hint: by definition, given any basis, every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of said basis, including all elements of any other basis.

Comment: Here the author is probably working under the hypothesis that prossibly $n\ne m$, so that he may later use the fact that invertible matrices are square to prove $n=m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are bases of the same vector space $V$, and the dimension of a vector space is equal to the cardinality of any basis of that vector space. It follows that $|B| = |C|$ giving $m = n$.